# Hybris Synchronization error for custom attribute

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, data-synchronization, backoffice

I have added a new attribute OOTB (BundleTemplate) to Product (this attribute is catalog aware) and everytime I  try to synchronize a product I get this error:

```
ERROR [000001KN::de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncJob] (000001KN) [CatalogVersionSyncMaster] sync ended with 4 unfinished items - see last sync media for details
ERROR [000001KN::de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncJob] (000001KN) [CatalogVersionSyncJob] Finished synchronization in 0d 00h:00m:00s:999ms. There were errors during the synchronization!
```

With this info I just can't find the reason why the sync isn't working , is there any way to debug this to get a better LOG ?

Comment: Can you add the items.xml configuration for the new attribute and how did you save the new attribute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator#copy() Line 166

Solved!

Comment: could you plz explain how you solved the problem? I am facing the same problem